# Simple select statement in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle

I have the following query:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_GetRegions 
(
pRegionID IN REGIONS.REGION_ID%TYPE,
pCountry  OUT COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME%TYPE,
pRegion   OUT  REGIONS.REGION_NAME%TYPE
)
IS

BEGIN

  SELECT c.Country_Name,
         r.Region_Name 

  INTO  pCountry, 
        pRegion      
  FROM COUNTRIES c 
  INNER JOIN REGIONS r 
  ON r.REGION_ID = c.REGION_ID
  WHERE r.REGION_ID = pRegionID
  ;



END SP_GetRegions;
```

And i'm trying to execute with the following command:

```
EXECUTE sp_getregions (1);
```

And I'm retrieving the following error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
EXECUTE sp_getregions (1)
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_GETREGIONS'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: You have defined the procedure with three parameters, but call it with one parameter only. Where do you think `pCountry` and `pRegion` will be returned?

Comment: the columns c.Country_Name,  r.Region_Name  ?

Comment: this was the last version in my proc:

create or replace PROCEDURE SP_GetRegions 
(
pRegionID IN REGIONS.REGION_ID%TYPE
)
IS

BEGIN

  SELECT c.Country_Name,
         r.Region_Name 
   
  FROM COUNTRIES c 
  INNER JOIN REGIONS r 
  ON r.REGION_ID = c.REGION_ID
  WHERE r.REGION_ID = pRegionID
  ;
  
 
END SP_GetRegions;

but i retrieve this error: Error(9,3): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement and i dont know why D:

Comment: @CarlosAlejandrodelosReyes Please, [edit] your question if you need to provide additional details (esp. code).

Comment: Somewhat similar: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102146/procedure-doesnt-have-compatible-arguments/102164#102164

Answer (score 1):

As @mustaccio said, you're calling a procedure with three parameters, but only passing one in. You need to pass externally-defined variables for the OUT parameters to populate.

Since you seem to be using SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, you could create client bind variables with the `variable` command and pass those, then print their values:

```
variable lCountry varchar2(30);
variable lRegion varchar2(30);
execute sp_getregions (1, :lCountry, :lRegion);
print lCountry
print lRegion
```

That's only really going to be useful to test the procedure. You'd be more likely to define PL/SQL variables and call the procedure from a block or another procedure, etc.:

```
declare
  lCountry COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME%TYPE;
  lRegion REGIONS.REGION_NAME%TYPE;
begin
  sp_getregions (1, lCountry, lRegion);
  -- do something with the local variables
end;
/
```

However, your procedure is only going to work when there is a single country in the region. If the region has no countries (which is unlikely) then you'd get a no-data-found exception; and if the region has more than one country (which is likely) you'd get a too-many-rows exception. [The `select ... into` construct](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm) has to get exactly one row of data in the result set.

As it isn't obvious how you want to use or consume the returned data I can't tell if you actually need a function that returns a ref cursor, or [a collection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm).

A basic procedure using an OUT ref cursor would be:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_GetRegions 
(
  pRegionID IN REGIONS.REGION_ID%TYPE,
  pCursor   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN

  OPEN pCursor FOR
    SELECT c.Country_Name,
           r.Region_Name 
    FROM COUNTRIES c 
    INNER JOIN REGIONS r 
    ON r.REGION_ID = c.REGION_ID
    WHERE r.REGION_ID = pRegionID
    ;

END SP_GetRegions;
/
```

And you could then call that using a bind variable and print the results:

```
variable lCursor refcursor;
exec SP_GetRegions(1, :lCursor);
print lCursor;
```

It would be more usual to use a function though:

```
drop PROCEDURE SP_GetRegions;
create or replace FUNCTION SP_GetRegions 
(
  pRegionID IN REGIONS.REGION_ID%TYPE
)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
  lCursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

  OPEN lCursor FOR
    SELECT c.Country_Name,
           r.Region_Name 
    FROM COUNTRIES c 
    INNER JOIN REGIONS r 
    ON r.REGION_ID = c.REGION_ID
    WHERE r.REGION_ID = pRegionID
    ;

  RETURN lCursor;
END SP_GetRegions;
/
```

You can call that from PL/SQL, or from plain SQL:

```
select SP_GetRegions(1) from dual;

COUNTRY_NAME                             REGION_NAME               
---------------------------------------- ------------------------- 
Belgium                                  Europe                    
Switzerland                              Europe                    
Germany                                  Europe                    
Denmark                                  Europe                    
France                                   Europe                    
Italy                                    Europe                    
Netherlands                              Europe                    
United Kingdom                           Europe
```

Comment: I just want to execute this query into the stored procedure.. how can i do that :) ?:


  `SELECT c.Country_Name,
         r.Region_Name 
   

  FROM COUNTRIES c 
  INNER JOIN REGIONS r 
  ON r.REGION_ID = c.REGION_ID
  WHERE r.REGION_ID = 2`
  

Using pRegionID as a filter in the where clause, that is all :), it is possible like T-SQL or not ? that is my question... :) regards.

Comment: @CarlosAlejandrodelosReyes - what do you want to do with the results of the query? They have to go somewhere. Assuming you do need to do this in a procedure at all, and you don't just want a simple SQL query executed in your client, with no PL/SQL at all.

Comment: I just want to see the retrieved data, i mean the resultset, that is all :), but by a stored procedure.

Comment: @CarlosAlejandrodelosReyes - the procedure runs in the database, it doesn't itself produce anything you can see. If you only ever want to see the result set, don't use a procedure, use plain SQL. If you will be calling this from somewhere else that will use the data, you need to know *how* it will use it.

Comment: @CarlosAlejandrodelosReyes - I've added a ref cursor approach. That might not be what your calling application expects though.